# How can I use regex for name on find command?

Tags: regex, find

I have a find command like this:

```
find /root/newdir/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f
```

output like this:

```
/root/newdir/test.log
/root/newdir/test2.log
/root/newdir/tmp_test3.log
/root/newdir/test.zip
```

I need to find files that start `test` and end `.log`. Sometimes I need complex regex too. I try `-regex` for my example like this, but does not work:

```
find /root/newdir/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -regex "^test*.log$"
```

How can I use regex like `^ $` characters on find command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the output is /path/to/file/test2.log for example you can't use ^ since the beginning of the line should be something like /path/to/file.

In this case what you can do is:

`find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -regex ".*/temp[^\/]*log$"`

Now you'll only find files after last / with the required regex.